# Laravel 5 check if pivot data is already in database

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox

Got a ManyOnMany system (3 tables, `projects`, `users`, `project_user`)

Many users can work on a project, and a user can have many projects.

When checkbox = checked it sends the database to the pivot table.

Now I'm facing the problem that everytime I click the project/user id will get send to the `project_user` table. 
And I need to have the checkbox already checked when the user is actually added to the project.

So how I see it: the form::checkbox has a third function checked or not checked, and with an if/else statement in my controller.edit I will have a validation somehow. Please help me!

Blade:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{$user->firstname}} {{$user->middlename}} {{$user->lastname}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {!! Form::checkbox('contribute['.$user->id.']', '1', $checkifinproject) !!}
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Controller:

```
public function edit($id, Project $project)
{
    $users = User::all();

    $project = $this->project->find($id);


    if ($users == $project)
    {
        $checkifinproject = 'checked';
    }
    else {

    }


    return view('project.edit', ['project' => $project, 'id' => 'edit', 'project_id' => $id], compact('users'));
}



public function update(CreateProjectRequest $request)
{
    if($request->get('contribute'))
    {
        foreach($request->get('contribute') as $k => $contribute)
        {
            if($contribute == 1)
            {
                $project = $this->project->find($request->project_id);
                $project->users()->attach($k);
            }
        }
    }

    $project = $this->project->find($request->project_id);
    $project->fill($request->input())->save();

    return redirect('project');
}
```

Model:

User

```
public function projects() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project', 'project_user', 'user_id', 'project_id');
}
```

Project

```
public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'project_user', 'project_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: how do you define eloquent relations. you can use `has` or `whereHas` built in function

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you are comparing two things that will never be the same and trying to determine if that user belongs to the project.  A better thing to do would be to query all the users with their projects and as you loop through the users, check to see that the project you are modifying is one of the projects the user belongs to.

That can be done like this...

#### Controller

```
public function edit($id, Project $project)
{
    $users = User::with('projects')->get();
    $project = $this->project->find($id);

    return view('projects.edit', ['users' => $users, 'project' => $project]);
}
```

#### View

```
@foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{$user->firstname}} {{$user->middlename}} {{$user->lastname}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {!! Form::checkbox('contribute['.$user->id.']', '1', $user->projects->contains('id', $project->id)) !!}
            </td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Is there someway I can contact you? You helped me pretty good last times aswell with good explanation and since I'm a beginner you're helping me pretty good. This didn't solve my problem by the way

Comment: I can't talk in the chat.